# Unable to install XAMPP services

Tags: mysql, apache, service, xampp

I am currently using XAMMP v3.2.4 and i need to install apache and mysql service.
I was able to install these on pervious tries by running xampp-control.exe using Run as Administrator and then marking the check boxes. But now i am unable to mark those check boxes.
I also tried using command line to run xammp-control.exe but nothing changed.

[xampp-control.exe screenshot by running as administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V76dh.png)

Comment: According to the screenshot, you already have apache and mysql running on your computer.

Comment: yes they are running but i still need to install them for development purposes

Comment: Why? If you want a separate dev environment, then use another computer. If you use 1 computer, then why don't you create just a separate database in mysql and separate virtual folder in apache?